# scanf works before its execution point

Tags: c

I tried a simple program..function returning integer and character pointer..after i run that code i found some weird acting by scanf..I tried to print message(enter a,b:) read two integer inputs and message(enter c,d:) read two char inputs.but at run time..i found that input for the char c is read rightafter i enter the inputs for a,b..
for eg:
enter a,b: 10
20
enter c,d: g
it gets only one input(for d) and input for c is **newline** after 20..
for eg 2:
enter a,b: 10
20a
enter c,d: g
it gets only one input(for d) and input for c is **a** after 20..
why is this happening..please clarify it

```
 int* add(int *a,int *b)
{
    return (*a>*b?a:b);
}  
char* charret(char *c,char *d)
{
     return (*c>*d?c:d);
 }

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    char c,d;

    printf("\n\t\tFUNCTION RETURNING INTEGER POINTER\n\t");
    printf("Enter the Number A and B:");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("\tEnter the character c :");
    scanf("%c %c",&c,&d);
    printf("The Biggestt Value is : %d\n\t",*add(&a,&b));
    printf("\n\tThe character c= %c hi d= %c",c,d);
 //   scanf("%c",&d);
    printf("\n\tThe Biggestt Value is : %c", *charret(&c,&d));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Flushall() may help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%c` will read *any* character, including the newline character from your previous entry.  If you want to read the first non-whitespace character, add a space before %c in your format string:

```
    scanf(" %c %c",&c,&d);
        /* ^ added space */
```

This will cause `scanf()` to eat any number of whitespaces before reading the character.

Answer (score 1):

For most `scanf()` specifiers, any *leading* whitespace is skipped.  `%c` is an exception to this, because it reads a single character value, including whitespace characters.  Keep in mind when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you've sent a `'\n'` to the input buffer.

> scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);

Reads in two numbers.  The `\n` at the end, from pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, is left in the buffer.

> scanf("%c %c",&c,&d);

Reads in two characters, the first of which will be the `\n` left in the buffer.  One way to get around this is:

> while (getch() != '\n');

This will eat everything up to an including a newline.  You can put that after the `scanf()` lines you know will leave a newline behind.